# Timezone names for .NET application in LINUX

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET CORE app.
While this code works in Windows:

```
 var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
 var currentDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(utcNow, "US Eastern Standard Time");
```

Will this work when deployed on Linux Kubernetes cluster - given the harcoded timezone name  `"US Eastern Standard Time"`

Or do I need to configure a different name?

Thanks

Anand

Answer (score 0):

For LINUX the name to use is `"EST"`

```
    var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
    string estTz = string.Empty;
#if RUN_ON_WINDOWS
    estTz = "US Eastern Standard Time";
#else
    estTz = "EST";
#endif
    var currentDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(utcNow, estTz); // nyse tz
```

In case you are interested we have `RUN_ON_WINDOWS` in `.csproj` that the TeamCity build process for LINUX or WINDOWS deployment overwrites accordingly.
`<ItemGroup Condition="'$(RunOnWindows)'=='true'">`

Answer (score 0):

For `TimeZoneInfo`, it has different ids for `Windows` and `Linux`, you could check this issue [TimeZoneInfo should have consistent Ids across Windows and Linux #2538](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2538).

For a possible workaround, you could try [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) like

```
    var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
    TimeZoneInfo tzi = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("Eastern Standard Time");
    var currentDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(utcNow, tzi.Id);
```

Comment: thanks! - good to know this approach and I tried it out but did not work for me. So went to approach I did that worked